# Sphere pinching

Tags: modeling

[image]

Hi

Im having issues with sphere pinching at the poles and I cant fix it. Does anyone have an easy fix for that, I cant figure it out.

Cheers

Alex

.[image]

Comment: Try plugging the UV output instead of the Generated output of the Texture Coordinate node into the Vector input of the Image Texture node and see if that helps.

Comment: It makes it even worse if I do that,

Comment: I think you'll need to share your Blend file here in that case. Pack the image into the blend file before sharing it via File > External Data > Pack Resources and then share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Answer (score 1):

Use *Generated* Texture Coordinate with *Box Projection* on the image texture, then turn the *Blend* up. There will still be "minor irregularities" around the seams, but it works well with most textures:

[image: BoxProject]